# Installation issues of Nitro Craft on Linux

Tags: craft3

I am having hard time installing Nitro Craft, I am probably have to do it manually. Spent entire day and not getting much of progress.
Anyways, I suspect that main issue I have is that I am on Linux, Ubuntu and using latest Docker Desktop, not as suggested Docker Engine.

1. First issue I encounter is that Nitro is looking for sock in /var/run/docker.sock but with Docker Desktop it is under home folder. Even though Docker context shows it should use that environment. So Nitro Init dose not work. I did workaround it with symlinking. Than Nitro Init seems to do some work, I see containers in Docker Desktop.

[image]

2. But I got another issue when I try to create project with Nitro create. It seems that it works, it also creates container, but composer really does not download anything. It builds folders, creates .htaccess files, but no other files. Not creating vendor folder at all. So I am getting Fatal errors when try to access website. I do have permission warning or error on .composer.lock too, during project creation or if I fire 'nitro compose install' later on.

Anyone manage to successfully install it in this environment?

Answer (score 1):

To answer myself, permissions were problem.
After nitro create, had to set 777 permissions to that newly created folder and run nitro composer install. Than nitro craft setup installs everything correctly and now have fully functional Nitro Craft CMS. Not really liking it to have 777, but at least I can do some tests.

I guess it is related to this https://github.com/craftcms/nitro/issues/391